# Internal working of GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am working with GSON in my current project, i am amazed to see its power and was wondering how did it work internally. How can a GSON object change the any object into JSON and vice versa. I did read the google user guide but the internal working is not mentioned their. Can anyone explain. Also this question might not appeal some people but i am new to android programming and was exploring things. Although i used gson successfully. But i do like to know its working methodology. Can any one explain.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could always get the source code and see for yourself...

Comment: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html for people like me who are wondering the same thing this link is very helpful just found it. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi link is not available now, 404 error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest that you do not perform recreation of objects and not force `GSON` except where it is needed. IMO, you have to use `GSON` anywhere where you have `REST` service, but `GSON` is more slower than java collections (`ArrayList` or `HashMap` or any other ...) and you will decrease app performances if you continue to use `GSON` everywhere.

Second reason is that when you perform object recreation, this is done in phone memory, and just for example, I had a problem with `JSON` (`GSON`) object which was exposed over service because it was 35-40MB and object creation uses over 70MB of RAM. There I had `OutOfMemoryException`, `MemoryExhaustedException` and more problems this kind.

If this limitations are not interested for you (you don't have large objects, or high speed is not required), then proceed to convert objects to GSON.

Comment: Dear friend you said you have to use gson when using restful api's is that mandatory? And if it is why?

Comment: I don't think this is a reasonable answer. Gson doesn't use more memory than manual conversion. It just does what you'd do manually, but automatically saving you time and typos.

Answer (score 2):

Gson's internals are built on three core types:

- [JsonReader](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) reads the elements in a JSON document from a stream.
- [JsonWriter](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html) writes the elements in a JSON document to a stream.
- [TypeAdapter](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) converts a single JSON element to a single object, or vice versa.

One key pattern is that TypeAdapter is implemented recursively. For example, the `TypeAdapter<FoodDelivery>` may delegate to a `TypeAdapter<Address>` and a `TypeAdapter<MenuItem>`. The `TypeAdapterFactory` interface makes it easy to build type adapters for arbitrary types.

One other key pattern is that `Gson` includes some awesome type adapters built-in by default. There's type adapters for primitives, strings, collections. Plus a special type adapter that takes an arbitrary Java class and converts it to a JSON object field-by-field.